# Ansible jinja dictionary create multiple files

Tags: dictionary, ansible, jinja2

I want to create multiple in ansible loop with jinja template, like that :

template_a

```
name = a
username = c
```

template_b

```
name = b
username = d
```

playbook.yml

```
- name: Create file from jinja
  template:
    src: "jinja.j2"
    dest: "template_{{ item }}"
    owner: "root"
    group: "root"
  with_items: "{{ jinja_var }}"
```

variables.yml

```
jinja_var:
  a: c
  b: d
```

jinja.j2

```
{% for (key,value) in jinja_var.iteritems() %}
name =  {{ key }}
username =  {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

I have got two same files :

```
name =  a
username =  1
name =  b
username =  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve the above mentioned output. Nothing complex though, with minor changes in the `playbook task` and `jinja` template would fix your issue.

When we add a for loop to iterate it would add each and every dictionary object present in the variable to the destination file. So, by directly adding `item` inside `jinja` and passing the `with_dict` to the task would mitigate the above mentioned problem.

`playbook.yml`

```
- name: Create file from jinja
  template:
    src: "jinja.j2"
    dest: "template_{{ item.key }}"
    owner: "root"
    group: "root"
  with_dict: "{{ jinja_var }}"
```

`jinja.j2`

```
name =  {{ item.key }}
username =  {{ item.value }}
```

**Output**

`template_a`

```
name =  a
username =  c
```

`template_b`

```
name =  b
username =  d
```

Comment: Nice answer.. I guess you misspelt `jinja` as `jinga` though.